# How do I install libimobiledevice?

Tags: software-installation

I have Precise and i want to get my iphone working with Rhythmbox, i have the latest package, but dont know how to install, the installer instructions look like gibberish to me.

Comment: Please link to to the instructions you're following?

Comment: It is the INSTALL file in the tar.gz

Answer (score 5):

I have not added the `pmcenery/ppa` to my software sources and I have `libimobiledevice` available in the Software Centre.

Simply open the Software Centre and type libimobiledevice in the search box, you should see a result like the following;

[image: libimobiledevice results]

Select it for installation and once complete you should get the following;

[image: libimobiledevice installed]

You should note that the version in the software centre is 1.1.1-4 and according to the [developers website](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) it is the development release.

[Launchpad has packages for all versions of Ubuntu from Oneiric to Quantal](https://launchpad.net/libimobiledevice)

Comment: Yes it is the development version, but it doesn't yet support iOS7 (see https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/20)

Answer (score 3):

Do this in terminal
 1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa`
 2. `sudo apt-get update`
 3. `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice`

If it says **Package not found**(it will most probably then):

1. `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Replace 
   `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu precise main` 
   and
    `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu precise main`
    by 
   `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu maverick main` 
   and
    `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu maverick main`.
3. Save the file.
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice`

If that does not work manaully download the ppa files for maverick(links below)(these are packages for 32 bit)
[Libgpod-common](https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa/+files/libgpod-common_0.8.0-1ubuntu1~maverick1_i386.deb)
[Libgpod4](https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa/+files/libgpod4_0.8.0-1ubuntu1~maverick1_i386.deb)
[Libimobiledevice1](https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa/+files/libimobiledevice1_1.0.6-1ubuntu1~maverick1_i386.deb)
[Libplist1](https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa/+files/libplist1_1.4-1ubuntu1~maverick1_i386.deb)
[libusbmuxd1](https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa/+files/libusbmuxd1_1.0.7-1ubuntu1~maverick1_i386.deb)
[usbmuxd](https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa/+files/usbmuxd_1.0.7-1ubuntu1~maverick1_i386.deb)

Answer (score 2):

Just type in the Terminal (Invoke it by pressing Cltr + Alt + T) this:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice2
```

From what I know, the package is already included in the default repositories.

Comment: Do an `apt search libimobile`, I found for 16.04LTS it to be `libimobiledevice6`, and it was already installed.